# I am connect mongo atlas with this code, but cannot create the database when i send these data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const url =
  "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.25pjvgx.mongodb.net/products_test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
  
  const createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    const newProduct = {
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price
    };
    const client = new MongoClient(url);
  
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const db = client.db();
      const result = db.collection('products').insertOne(newProduct);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.json({message: 'Could not store data.'});
    };
    client.close();
  
    res.json(newProduct);
  };
  
  const getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {};
  
  exports.createProduct = createProduct;
  exports.getProducts = getProducts;
```

send--
{
"name":"apple",
"price": 99
}

output-
{
"message": "Could not store data."
}

Where is the problem? I try to send the data to the database. But it doesn't work I can not find. please help me.

Comment: Now you need to rotate your credentials.

Comment: Can you you `console.log(error)`, it should have more info

Comment: I might be wrong here but I think you need to make sure you create the database manually. Try removing `/products_test` from the connection string to confirm

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can i rotate credentials?

Comment: @ShuvoRoy He means that you need to change your password now that you have posted it publicly on the internet

Answer (score 0):

i used `await` before `db.collection('products').insertOne(newProduct)`.It works for me